# Screen resolution error with none borderstyle form

Tags: c#, winforms, formborderstyle

I am using a form that `FormBorderStlye` property is `none` for `RoundedRactangle` form and I'm using some images. But I have a problem. I know why but don't know how to solve it. The reason of the problem is `Formborderstyle` is `none`. When I opened my Width: 1200, Height: 800 Form on a 800x600 screen it's deletes my form's outside parts.I really need immediate help.

let me be more specific,I created a new form,I set the Borderstyle to none.on 1366x768 screen resulotion displaying like this.

http://imageupload.org/en/file/180618/ss.jpg.html

but when I change my screen resulotion to 800x600 outside of the form is being deleted.you see there is not any 'button2' on my form.

http://imageupload.org/en/file/180624/ss-2.jpg.html

Thanks in advance.

The images at the  bottom of site,first image loading slow because of its size.you need to wait until image completely load for seeing it in orginal size.I uploaded it another site because of my reputation wasn't enough to upload stackoverflow

Comment: It sounds like you have the start position property set to centre?

Comment: yes I set it to center,is this for the reason ?

Comment: I think it is the problem. Change the position in the form load event so you can see the borders. The screen will not provide scrollbars. You must do that in your form.

Comment: sorry,did not work.thanks for reply.

Comment: I can't even find the screenshots for all the ads... I looked hard, too. Not worth the trouble. Stack Overflow provides an image hosting service.

Comment: Your form is bigger than your screen. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Why even try and explicitly set the size? Aren't you just trying to achieve the effect of having it fill the screen?

Any reason you can't just set

> Form.WindowState = FormWinddowState.Maximised

Comment: the problem is not filling form in to screen my problem is after maximized or whatever if my form is bigger than screen my objects that outside of the screen  like button,combobox etc. those objects is being deleted.please check the images  that i posted

Comment: I did - it looked like two things. First, that by setting the size explicitly instead of using Maximised, the size was wrong after the resolution changed. I suspect maximised would automatically respond to that. If not, you may have to listen to SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged to redo your size logic after a resolution change. Second, the control  disappearing is a layout issue. It looks like they're absolute positioned. You need to lay them out on the smallest resolution you will support and use Anchoring so they move according to the size of the form.